# How do I find which IP address softwareupdated daemon is downloading Mojave from?

Tags: terminal, network, software-update

I have started downloading macOS Mojave and went to Activity Monitor to check the download speed and it is disappointingly low. Activity Monitor shows me that a process called `softwareupdated` is downloading the update and the PID is 410. However doing `lsof -p 410` shows me nothing. How do I proceed?

Comment: Can you try and tell us the results of `sudo lsof -p 410 | grep TCP`?

Comment: @ankiiiiiii running `lsof` with `sudo` actually worked! Please convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lsof` doesn't always show the root processes running. So `sudo` to be used.

`sudo lsof -p PID | grep TCP`

PID to be replaced with the PID(Activity Monitor is one source.). TCP can be replaced with other protocols too. For unfiltered results removed the `| grep TCP` part.